# In Postman value is returned inside {} and I need to extract the values

Tags: json, postman

Normally I would use a test script like this:

```
let jdata = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("accountId",jdata.Id);
console.log(jdata.Id)
```

however the value being returned is inside curly braces {} and as a result the console logs the value as undefined and the enviroment value is being set as null.

Any suggestions on things to try to be able to extract the data?

Comment: Can you show us `console.log(jdata)`

Comment: Hi Rich,
response is:
{ReturnModel: {…}, JobNumber: null, MayRequireRerate: false}
ReturnModel: {…}
Id: 12
AccountNumber: "AN14136120"
Name: "AN14136120"
Reference: "A Ref 88"
VatCodeId: 1
DateCreated: "2022-07-04T09:12:16.8866589+01:00"
UserCreated: "Automated via Postman"
JobNumber: null
MayRequireRerate: false

Answer (score 0):

the response was to bring it down another level, though I wasnt sure oh how to do this.

By putting

```
console.log(jdata.ReturnModel.Id)
```

the value of the Id is returned